# Retrieving objects from a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

Guys, this is silly, but i got to ask

You have a     `private Map<String, String> dbMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

i am putting stuff in after having read the file like:

```
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
        int ix = line.indexOf("=");
        String key = line.substring(0, ix);
        String value = line.substring(ix + 1, line.length());
            ...
        dbMap.put(key, value);
        }
```

Once we done, you print it and your map shows what's inside

```
System.out.println(fc.getDbMap().keySet());

{MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS = something, DATABASE_PASSWD = something else}
```

when i try to get value assigned to particular key, i get null, when indeed key exists

Why?

```
System.out.println(fc.getDbMap().containsKey("DATABASE_PASSWD"));
false

System.out.println(fc.getDbMap().get("DATABASE_PASSWD"));
null
```

Comment: not enough information here... how do you put stuff into the map, and how are you sure that what you print is the same map as the one you are trying to call `containsKey()` ?

Comment: can you do a sysout of fc.getDbMap() - does that yeild the following?{MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS = something, DATABASE_PASSWD = something else}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are printing out keySet() and NOT the Map (as per code), so your keys look like "MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS = something" etc (or maybe the whole thing is key) -- yet you expect keys to be "MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS".
So you are building your Map incorrectly (or library you are asking to fill it).

If these are read from a property file, perhaps you are using wrong separator?